# cleartool: Error: A deliver_start preop trigger does not allow this operation

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have a very strange error today on windows ClearCase.
I encounter the following error while delivering from my old stream to the parent stream.
Meanwhile I made a new child stream on windows and delivered from there and it was OK.

The most amazing thing is I used the same old stream on unix and delivery completed without any problem.

What might be the reason behind this failure of my old stream on windows?

```
Do you wish to continue with this deliver operation?  [no] yes
cleartool: Warning: Trigger "dlvr_start_pre" has refused to let deliver_start proceed.
cleartool: Error: A deliver_start preop trigger does not allow this operation.
cleartool: Error: Unable to do integration.
cleartool: Error: Unable to deliver stream "...".
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find that "`dlvr_start_pre`" script and see what it does.
This isn't a script automatically put by ClearCase: it has been written and put in place by your ClearCase admin, in a path accessible form any Windows workstation.

But you also need to consider your current ClearCase client.
For instance, "[non-interactive triggers fail with warning about interactivity using CCRC or CCWeb](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266044)".

That old stream could also have been created with different rights (owner/group) than the new one (that happens if the `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment variable changes)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. dlvr_start_pre shouldn't have problem because delivery completed from another child stream and even from the same stream in different platform. what will be the another thing I should check?

Comment: @user2370590 you should still check what that script *does* in order to have a clue about what kind of difference (like the right difference I mention) you have to look for between that old stream and the newer ones.

Comment: @user2370590 and don't forget that a trigger can very much be defined just for windows clients, and not unix. In an interop environment, you define a trigger with the option `-win` and `-unix`, but you don't have to always use both. So a deliver working from unix doesn't mean much.